# Polygonize error

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, rasterio, polygonize

I try to vectorize raster layer. Each pixel has value from 1 to 128. It the simplest and has only 1 band.

[image]

I use polygonize tool and I get an error.
[image]

Initially I got my raster from rasterize tool (maybe it matters). I saved it on a disk, but it also doesn't work.

How can I do this? I'm new in QGIS and I've hardly worked with raster layers.

Comment: By the error message there is some problem with creating the output layer. I suppose that you used the "GDAL Polygonize (Raster to Vector)" tool. What do you see in the "GDAL/OGR console call" box?

Comment: Hello! I don't know how to see GDAL/OGR console call box. I'm using  upper menu: Raster - Conversion - Polygonize. I noticed that if the output layer is not temporary, then there is no error. But I want to implement polygonization through PyQGIS and saving is not very suitable for me. Is it normal that I have to save it to disk?

Comment: Have you scrolled down in the parameters window? "Save to temporary file" is the default and it should work. However, I got the same error than you. The reason for the error is earlier in the log: `Creating output ... Local/Temp/processing_itbYJS/f14705232a734c5786af2c76250a18d6/OUTPUT.xtf of format Interlis 2.` It means that QGIS selects a file format that is not suitable for the task. Please write mail to qgis-users list and ask if this bug is already found. The QGIS tools saves the result into a temp file but with Python it should be possible to use https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/mem.html.

Comment: Please include error messages as text. Images are not legible on all devices, and cannot be searched by others with the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could re-produce the error with QGIS 3.35, installed with OSGeo4W.

The command log shows that with the default setting QGIS tries to save the polygonozed result into an Interlis 2 file. This format obviously does not support a method that is called "CreateLayer", and the process fails.

> Creating output ...
> Local/Temp/processing_itbYJS/f14705232a734c5786af2c76250a18d6/OUTPUT.xtf
> of format Interlis 2

As a workaround is is possible to de-activate this driver from the settings Options - GDAL - Vector drivers.

[image]

After restarting QGIS without Interlis drivers it decided to use GeoPackage as the storage format for the temporary layer.

```
gdal_polygonize.bat test.tif -b 1 -f "GPKG" ... Temp/processing_pIiZIV/a80ec29dc5ba435bb8d1b22d7796e291/OUTPUT.gpkg OUTPUT DN
```

Comment: Thank you for help!