# Raster to vector bunch of errors

Tags: vector, raster-conversion, polygonize

[image: Error log]

I'm having a problem where I can't convert my raster file to vector using the raster menu, I'm kind of new to the area and some errors appear that I have no idea how to fix. I know I can do something similar using the GRASS algorithm, but I can't do improved smoothing.

> !QGIS version: 3.36.0-Maidenhead
> QGIS code revision: 09951dc0
> Qt version: 5.15.3
> Python version: 3.9.18
> GDAL version: 3.8.4
> GEOS version: 3.12.1-CAPI-1.18.1
> PROJ version: Rel. 9.3.1, December 1st, 2023
> PDAL version: 2.6.0 (git-version: 3fced5)
> Algorithm started at: 2024-03-04T15:18:34
> Algorithm 'Polygonize (raster to vector)' starting…
> Input parameters:
> { 'BAND' : 1, 'EIGHT_CONNECTEDNESS' : False, 'EXTRA' : '', 'FIELD' : 'DN', 'INPUT' : 'C:/geoproII/dados/editados/limites_mun/SRTM_largbuff5kmrec.tif', 'OUTPUT' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT' }
> GDAL command:
> gdal_polygonize.bat C:/geoproII/dados/editados/limites_mun/SRTM_largbuff5kmrec.tif -b 1 -f "Interlis 2" C:/Users/leo/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_YNZjcV/7eaf7646028c4d4dbd684d0f22c93281/OUTPUT.xtf OUTPUT DN
> GDAL command output:
> Creating output C:/Users/leo/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_YNZjcV/7eaf7646028c4d4dbd684d0f22c93281/OUTPUT.xtf of format Interlis 2.
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS33~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\gdal_argparse.py", line 226, in main
> self.doit(**kwargs)
> File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS33~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\osgeo_utils\gdal_polygonize.py", line 351, in doit
> return gdal_polygonize(**kwargs)
> File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS33~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\osgeo_utils\gdal_polygonize.py", line 162, in gdal_polygonize
> dst_layer = dst_ds.CreateLayer(
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'CreateLayer'
> Process returned error code 1
> Execution completed in 1.00 seconds
> Results:
> OUTPUT: C:/Users/leo/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_YNZjcV/7eaf7646028c4d4dbd684d0f22c93281/OUTPUT.xtf
> Loading resulting layers
> The following layers were not correctly generated.
> • C:/Users/leo/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_YNZjcV/7eaf7646028c4d4dbd684d0f22c93281/OUTPUT.xtf
> You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the Default output vector layer extension (in Settings->Options->Processing->General) to a value other than "xtf" e.g. to the value "gpkg" (GeoPackage) which is the default for such option.

Comment: But if the default output format seems to be correct and process still fails, have a look at https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/477617/30184 and deactivate the Interlis drivers.

Comment: it worked perfectly, hadn't gone to those settings yet, thank you very much